# Matlab array arithmetic inaccuracy

Tags: arrays, matlab, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

When i am trying to simulate my sine approximation in matlab i found a strange problem. The problem is that when i apply my function to an array, it returns one results, whereas applying functions to individual values ​​gives a slightly different result.

I was able to get same behaviour in this example:

```
z = single(0:0.001:1);
F = @(x) (x.^2 - single(1.2342320e-001)).*x.^2;  %some test function

z(999)        % Returns 9.9800003e-001
F(z(999))     % Returns 8.6909407e-001
temp = F(z);  
temp(999)     % Voila! It returns 8.6909401e-001
```

Also I found a few things. One is that first result is right (not the latter). Second, is that rearrangement of terms **sometimes** solves the problem. So i have no idea how to get rid of that.

Comment: All floating-point arithmetic is somewhat inaccurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using single-precision numbers, both results are "equal" (difference is smaller than the relative accuracy of the `single` type). The following statement evaluates to true:

```
max(abs( arrayfun(F,z) - F(z) )) < eps('single')
```

---

#### EDIT

If you really want to have control over this, you can try disabling the MATLAB accelerator to force it to use the same execution paths for both regular and vectorized code:

```
feature('jit', 'off')
feature('accel', 'off')
max(abs( arrayfun(F,z) - F(z) ))

feature('jit', 'on')
feature('accel', 'on')
max(abs( arrayfun(F,z) - F(z) ))
```

The result for the first/second respectively:

```
ans =
     0
ans =
   5.9605e-08
```

Obviously, by default both the accelerator and the just-in-time compiler are turned on.

Comment: Hmm... Yes you're write. But I thought that in this case binary representation of the two numbers would be equal, but it is not.

Comment: it works, but not always. Anyway thanks. The more solutions the better

Comment: @Menzoda: just for reference, could you share an example where it didn't work

Comment: Heh. I remember that I played with numbers and somthing goes wrong with accel feature. But now I can't get the same behavior.

Comment: Out of all this I realized that floating point is a very delicate matter. And if we speaking specifically about my problem, your solution probably best.

Answer (score 3):

Single-precision only has up to 7 decimal digits of meaningful precision, so to say that `8.6909407e-001` is "right" and `8.6909401e-001` is "wrong" is not terribly meaningful in this situtaion.

Floating-point arithmetic is also sensitive to the order of operations, as you've already found.  It's likely that Matlab subtly changes the order of calculations when operating on a matrix rather than a scalar.

Comment: The fact is that I want to get zero-error approximation with the single-precision numbers. And I've probably already done it, but I cannot be convinced in that because of Matlab. So is there some way to control this "automatic" calculation order changes?

Comment: No. You have no control over that.

Answer (score 1):

For vector arithmetic, MatLab's linear algebra library may use SIMD instructions instead of x87 FPU, and the precision will be slightly different.

The relative error is very very small, and shouldn't break any reasonably designed calculation.  Are you testing for floating-point equality?

Comment: Nope. I just want to analyze absolute and relative error of my approximation. Because of this hmm... anomaly i observe a little inaccuracy while in reality it is not. It's quite unpleasant.

Answer (score 1):

I can guarantee that any device that uses floating point math will *not*, in fact, deliver binary-equal results for math-equal expressions.  Try the equivalent of the following MATLAB on your various platforms:

```
a = [repmat(1, 10000, 1); 1e16];
format long
sum(a)
sum(flipud(a))
```

Results:

```
1.000000000001000e+16
1.000000000000000e+16
```

Addition is commutative, so the expressions are mathematically equivalent.  But the order matters in floating-point world.  Obviously, adding 10000 1's in sequence should present no problem for a floating-point, when the accumulation value is around 0.  But once the floating-point has "floated" to 1e16, 1 is simply too small to be represented, so it's never added.

Here's an extra wrinkle:  The x87 FPU computes in extended precision (80 bits), internally.  So FPU code will give you a different answer, if the compiler decides to keep the intermediate results inside the FPU.  If instead it decides to spill intermediate results to the stack, then you're back to 64.  If it decides to compute using the SSE instructions, then you're back to 64.

These various MATLAB tricks suggested in the other answers might get you close enough for your problem.  But if you're really after perfect modelling of your system, you'll probably need a simulation framework that is more controllable.  Perhaps using `vpa`, with conversion to the correct number of bits at each step.  Or switch to C or C++, paying extremely careful attention to the optimizer control settings.

Or mathematically compute the bounds on your error based on the input scaling, and verify that your answer is always below the bound.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. All answers are right, but they doesn't solve the problem. All I want is that mathematically-equal expressions brings binary-equal result, regardless of if I use scalar or vector arithmetic. The result that brings me FPU in my Cortex-M4, my calculator, and many other programms and devices, but not Matlab.

So far, the only solution that I see is to use `for`-loops instead of vector arithmetic. Ugly, but it works.

**EDIT**

Thanks to the responses we have some more solutions for this problem.